# Lax-Wendroff and Crank-Nicolson Matlab simulation of linear advection

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, finite-difference-methods

I am implementing two schemes: Lax-Wendroff and Crank Nicolson to solve the PDE linear advection in Matlab. My simulation seems to run; however, between the transition in time space the numerical solutions obtained do not seem to look right.

This is the schemes that I implement:

[image]
[image]

In Matlab implementation, I am trying to solve $v_{j}^{n+1}$ which is denoted as v_new. For Lax-Wendroff, I implement it as the for-loop updating and I take into account the periodic solution. For Crank-Nicolson, I make a matrix for both $v_{j}^{n+1}$ and $v_{j}^{n+1}$ because it is implicit method.

The following is my Matlab implementation. I cannot fix as I describe above.

```
% the advection speed
a=1.;
% number of grid points in space (not counting the point at x=1, which is the same as the point at x=0, due to the periodicity)
N=51;
% spatial step
h =(1./(N));
% safety constant for stability (should be smaller than 1)
cfl=.8;
% CFl timestep limit for the explicit methods
dt=cfl*h/a;
% time at which we want to end the simulation
t_end=1.;    
% number of timesteps to be taken
n_it=t_end/dt;
% number of methods: Lax-Wendroff vs Crank-Nicolson. 
n_methods=2;
% initialize some arrays
% spatial grid (not including the point at x=1, which is the same as the point at x=0, due to the periodicity)
x=(0:h:1-h);
% temporal grid
t=(0:dt:n_it*dt);
% arrays for the numerical approximations at times n and n+1
v_new=zeros(N,n_methods);
v_old=zeros(N,n_methods);
% array for the exact solution
v_exact=zeros(N,1);
    
% the initial condition
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
for i=1:n_methods
    v_old(:,i)=exp(-50*(x-.5).^2);
end
[ACN,BCN]=mat_linadv_CN(N,a,h,dt);  




    
% the main iteration loop
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
for iter = 1:n_it
% method 1: Lax-Wendroff(treat the first and last separately into account the periodicity)
for i=2:N-1
    v_new(i,1)=v_old(i,1) + (((a^2)*dt)/2*h^2)*(v_old(i+1,1)-2*v_old(i,1)+ ... 
                         v_old(i-1,1))-(a*dt)*(v_old(i+1,1)-v_old(i-1,1));
end 
    v_new(1,1)=v_old(1,1) + (((a^2)*dt)/2*h^2)*(v_old(2,1)-2*v_old(1,1)+...
                    v_old(N,1))-(a*dt)*(v_old(2,1)-v_old(N,1)); 
        v_new(N,1)=v_old(N,1) + (((a^2)*dt)/2*h^2)*(v_old(1,1)-2*v_old(N,1)+...
                   v_old(N-1,1))-(a*dt)*(v_old(1,1)-v_old(N-1,1));
% method 2: Crank-Nicolson. 
v_new(:,2)=ACN\(BCN*v_old(:,2));
% the exact solution with a=1
v_exact(:) = exp(-50*(x-a*t(iter+1)-.5).^2) + ...
             exp(-50*(x-a*t(iter+1)+.5).^2);
% graphical output
plot(x,v_exact(:),'^r-')
hold on

for i=1:n_methods
    plot(x,v_new(:,1),'*b-')
    plot(x,v_new(:,2),'+g-')
end
axis([0 1 -.2 1.2])
xlabel('x')
ylabel('v')
title('linadv simulation')
legend('exact','Lax-Wendroff','Crank-Nicolson'); 
grid on;
grid minor; 
hold off
pause(0.001)

% prepare for the next iteration

v_old=v_new;

end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%implicit method Crank-Nicolson (CN): 
function [ACN,BCN]=mat_linadv_CN(N,a,h,dt)
e=ones(N,1); 

const1=(-a/(4*h));
const2=(1/dt);
const3=(a/(4*h));

ACN=spdiags([const1*e const2*e const3*e],[-1 0 1], N,N); 
ACN(1,N)=const3;
ACN(N,1)=const1; 

BCN=spdiags([const1*e const2*e const3*e],[-1 0 1],N,N); 
BCN(1,N)=const3;
BCN(N,1)=const1;
end
```

Comment: The Lax-Wendroff scheme has a critical omission. The principal idea is to use $$v(x,t+dt)=v(x,t)+v_t(x,t)dt+\tfrac12v_{tt}(x,t)\,dt^2+O(dt^3)\\=v(x,t)-\frac{a\,dt}{2\,dx}(v(x+dx,t)-v(x-dx,t))+\frac{a^2\,dt^2}{2\,dx^2}(v(x+dx,t)-2v(x.t)+v(x-dx,t))+O(dt^3,\,dt\,dx^2).$$ Meaning that the third term in the cited formula is missing a factor $\Delta t$.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the Lax-Wendroff part, see code below. There were several typos in the coefficients and in the expression of the scheme, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Wendroff_method). These remarks might help you fix the whole thing. By the way, note that alternative Matlab implementations are available on this site, see related posts.

```
% the advection speed
a=1.;
% number of grid points in space (not counting the point at x=1, which is the same as the point at x=0, due to the periodicity)
N=51;
% spatial step
h =(1./(N));
% safety constant for stability (should be smaller than 1)
cfl=.8;
% CFl timestep limit for the explicit methods
dt=cfl*h/a;
% time at which we want to end the simulation
t_end=1.;    
% number of timesteps to be taken
n_it=floor(t_end/dt);
% initialize some arrays
% spatial grid (not including the point at x=1, which is the same as the point at x=0, due to the periodicity)
x=(0:h:1-h);
% temporal grid
t=(0:dt:n_it*dt);
% arrays for the numerical approximations at times n and n+1
v_new=zeros(N,1);
v_old=zeros(N,1);
% array for the exact solution
v_exact=zeros(N,1);

% the initial condition
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
v_old(:)=exp(-50*(x-.5).^2);

% the main iteration loop
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
for iter = 1:n_it
% method 1: Lax-Wendroff(treat the first and last separately into account the periodicity)
for i=2:N-1
    v_new(i)=v_old(i) + (a^2*dt^2/(2*h^2))*(v_old(i+1)-2*v_old(i)+ ... 
                     v_old(i-1))-(a*dt/(2*h))*(v_old(i+1)-v_old(i-1));
end 
    v_new(1)=v_old(1) + (a^2*dt^2/(2*h^2))*(v_old(2)-2*v_old(1)+...
                    v_old(N))-(a*dt/(2*h))*(v_old(2,1)-v_old(N)); 
    v_new(N)=v_old(N) + (a^2*dt^2/(2*h^2))*(v_old(1)-2*v_old(N)+...
                    v_old(N-1))-(a*dt/(2*h))*(v_old(1)-v_old(N-1));
% the exact solution with a=1
v_exact(:) = exp(-50*(x-a*t(iter+1)-.5).^2) + ...
             exp(-50*(x-a*t(iter+1)+.5).^2);
% graphical output
plot(x,v_exact(:),'^r-')
hold on

plot(x,v_new(:),'*b-')
axis([0 1 -.2 1.2])
xlabel('x')
ylabel('v')
title('linadv simulation')
legend('exact','Lax-Wendroff'); 
grid on;
grid minor; 
hold off
pause(0.001)

% prepare for the next iteration

v_old=v_new;

end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think I got how it was wrong. The coefficients I implemented were not correct.